# Turning a list of sheet names into a data validation

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Below is a code I am trying to turn into a part of a larger code. A little background is that I'm trying to make a list of sheet names, that I can make into a data validation list. Then go into the sheet I've picked and create another data validation list from that sheet. (this all happens in my master sheet) The code below is a custom formula that I pair with googleclock. It creates a list and then I use that list to create my data validation list. The code I'm trying to write is my way of skipping the middle man and making it dynamic.

```
  function sheetnames() {
   var out = new Array()
   var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
   for (var i=2 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) out.push( [ 
   sheets[i].getName() ] )
     return out 
                }
```

How does one skip the middle man and make a data validation list of names (based off the sheet tab names)?

I also have all of the sheet names auto populate cell A1 in each sheet if that can help.

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: What do you mean by "googleclock"?

Comment: @Rubén if you add add "googleclock" to a function (in my case a custom function). The formula reacts as the sheet refreshes. My formula is 
      =sheetnames(googleclock())   and to my knowledge this will help keep everything up to date even if you change the data you are pulling from

Comment: The built-in googleclock function was retired few years ago

Comment: @Rubén it still seems to work for my sheets

Answer (score 1):

So, since my question was lacking in some respects I decided to just work on the issue and figure it out. Then share my findings! Below is a script that makes a list of all of your sheet tab names, then with that list I used a macro to make a data validation list. The last part of my script looks at my data validation choice and auto populates the remaining rows with a list of items from the specific sheet name.

```
    function listSheetNames() {

     var names = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()
        .map(function(s) {
            return [s.getName()];
        })
     SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0]
        .getRange(1, 1, names.length, names[0].length).setValues(names)

     Logger.log(names);

     }

      function onEdit () {

  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ordersheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var reference = ordersheet.getActiveCell().getValue();

     var range = ordersheet.getRange(2, 1, ordersheet.getLastRow()).getValues();


  if(reference = range) { 

 var sheetName = ordersheet.getActiveCell().getValue(); 
 var pullName = data.getSheetByName(sheetName);
 var datass = pullName.getRange(1, 1, pullName.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

 var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(datass).build(); 
 ordersheet.getActiveCell().offset(1, 0, 100).setDataValidation(validationRule);

    Logger.log(pullName); 

  }}
```

So this is a bit of a work around. I am still trying to figure out how to take my "listSheetnames" script and directly turn that into a data validation list. Any help would be much appreciated.

The workbook i'm trying to create is supposed to help with creating order sheets and the larger version I have made of this has prices attached. It may be a bit of a niche script idea but I hope it is useful.

Let me know what you think! 
(link Below)

[data validation with sheet names](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FD2h3Ow4qUwNoRDd_VQUaa3I8_jEQhDlmZqTR74AEYU/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function sheetnames() {
  var out=[];
  var sheets=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for(var i=2;i<sheets.length;i++){
    out.push([sheets[i].getName()]);
  }
  return out;//this is a 2d column array, hence useable in setValues() 
}
```