# Take list of sheets and create dropdown onSelectionChange

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

was asked in 2018 [Turning a list of sheet names into a data validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53748948/turning-a-list-of-sheet-names-into-a-data-validation)
I want to create a dataValadation dropdown by getting a list of sheets onSelectionChange(e). I can get a list for the sheets I want but it won't make a dropdown.
I am trying to make it so when you make a new sheet and go back to the "Main" the "A1" cell will create a new dropdown with the added sheet.

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (src.getName() == 'Main'){ 
    const excluded = src.getSheets().filter(sheet =>!["DontAdd"].includes(sheet.getName()));
    var names = excluded.map(function(s) {
            return [s.getName()];
        })
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(names).build();
    src.getRange("A1").setDataValidation(rule);
  }
}
```

Tried putting it into a list of names but still no go.

Answer (score 0):

need to use SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() instead of src

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
      const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
      if (src.getName() == 'Main'){ 
        const excluded = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().filter(sheet =>!["DontAdd"].includes(sheet.getName()));
        var names = excluded.map(function(s) {
                return [s.getName()];
            });
        var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(names, true).build();
        src.getRange("A1").setDataValidation(rule);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).